# Loading and calling a tensorflow saved model becomes very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have tensorflow keras model as below.

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_1, emb_size_1, vocab_2, emb_size_2):
        super().__init__()

        self.embedding_1 = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.IntegerLookup(
                    vocabulary=vocab_1, mask_token=None
                ),
                tf.keras.layers.Embedding(
                    len(vocab_1) + 1,
                    emb_size_1,
                    embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
                ),
            ]
        )

        self.embedding_2 = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
                    vocabulary=vocab_2, mask_token=None
                ),
                tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(vocab_2) + 1, emb_size_2),
            ]
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        _embeddings = [
            self.embedding_1(inputs["emb_1"]),
            self.embedding_2(inputs["emb_2"]),
        ]

        return tf.concat(_embeddings, axis=1)
```

If I just use the trained model as is, it's pretty fast.

but the problem is, when I save the trained model and then load it and use it, it's very slow.

and I also noticed a drop in GPU utilization.

It happened after I upgrade my tensorflow version from 2.5.0 to latest (2.12.0).

---

1. use trained model as is

```py
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = MyModel()
    model.fit()

embeddings = model(input)  # Took 1s. GPU Util 20~30%
```

2. use loaded model

```py
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = MyModel()
    model.fit()

model.save(path)
loaded_model = tf.keras.saving.load_model(path)
# also tried tf.saved_model.save, tf.saved_model.load. but same result

embeddings = loaded_model(input)  # Took 10s. GPU Util 1~5%
```

I've tried this on tensorflow 2.9.0 and above, and the results were the same.

Isn't it normal that the speed shouldn't drop?

---

UPDATE

I found it to be very fast when I tried `save_weights` and `load_weights`.

saving and loading weights are even faster than first trial (`use trained model as is`)

```py
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = MyModel()
    model.fit()

model.save_weights(path)

loaded_model = MyModel()
loaded_model.load_weights(path)

embeddings = loaded_model(input)  # Took 0.8s. GPU Util 20~30%
```

this is very interesting.